# Remote dropdown default value

Tags: semantic-ui

I have a form done with semantic-ui and one of the elements is a dropdown that has values pulled from a remote url. It works fine for adding things but how do I set a value for the dropdown when editing.

If a user searched for a country and submitted the form with `United Kingdom` how do I display the selected value when the user wants to edit the object?

```
$('.ui.dropdown.country_select').dropdown('setting', {
    apiSettings: {
        url: '../countries/{query}'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer after some digging:

```
var dd = $('.ui.dropdown.country_select').dropdown('setting', {
    apiSettings: {
        url: '../countries/{query}'
    }
});

dd.dropdown('set text', 'yahoo');
dd.dropdown('set value', 'google');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue but with a dropdown that was **multiple**, **searchable**, and **remote data**. For me, the solution was to seed ONLY the `<option>` tag(s) that corresponds with the default value. So, using your code sample:

```
$('.ui.dropdown.country_select').dropdown('setting', {
    apiSettings: {
        url: '../countries/{query}'
    }
});

// Assuming defaultValue = '1';

<select class="ui dropdown country_select">
  <option value="1" selected>Default Value Item</option>
</select>
```

Then the dropdown should overwrite the options with the remote source after initialization.